# Не работает Ansible Vault

Tags: ansible

Шифрую строку с помощью `ansible-vault encrypt_string 'password' --name 'ansible_ssh_pass'`

Получаю:
`ansible_ssh_pass: !vault | $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256 36633637636538333965646364353532613833306339353730326632633433663339336263333030 3634633734326236646338633434643062656132663333390a343632653166613561623635303739 31336264303163666265353332313233623666316235316465633966353964366233343635633134 6339353431643563340a326336616362386630303436356636666230396430336637653033353134`

При запуске бука пишет:

> 192.168.53.14 | FAILED! => {
> "msg": "Decryption failed (no vault secrets were found that could decrypt)"

Пробовал так-же подставлять через переменную, тоже не работает. Не могу разобраться почему.

Ключ `--ask-vault-pass` конечно-же использую при запуске.

Comment: https://itsecforu.ru/2019/08/26/%F0%9F%92%BD-%D1%88%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-ansible-vault-%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82/?ysclid=lc18tkcxf6702835972 читал же? Ну там где про файл с паролем.

Comment: Какая разница файл это или строка. В документации указаны оба варианта. Я пробовал разные способы, и с файлом, и с переменной, и с шифрованием строки, но никакого результата нет.

Comment: Можешь куда-нить скинуть архив с файлами, чтобы я попробовал? Или в вопросе распиши имена файлов и их содержимое.

Comment: `group_vars/
├── all.yml
├── bc_vars
├── kg_vars
└── sm_vars
`
Конфиг **all.yml**. Шифрую строку как выше указал. Если файл, то указываю через переменную. Сам файл кладу в корень Ansible

`ansible_user: user
ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ vault }}"
ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
ansible_become: True
ansible_become_method: sudo
ansible_become_user: root
ansible_become_ask_pass: False
ansible_become_pass: "{{ vault }}"`

Comment: А можно в вопрос вот это всё? Я из камента вот это выковыривать не собираюсь, а потом гадать кто из нас пробел пропустил.

Comment: По сути тебе отсюда нужно 2 строки понять, но можно и одну `ansible_ssh_pass: "{{ vault }}"`

Comment: Про какие пробелы ты, я хз. Тут три варианта. Либо подставить переменную напрямую, либо подставить переменную с путем к файлу, либо подставить зашифрованную строку.

Comment: Ну я не хочу копировать код из каментов. Тогда жди, кто захочет.